# Is it OK to move an old MySQL data folder to a new MySQL install's folder?

Tags: mysql, data-migration, osx-lion

I've installed MySQL on my Mac running lion using their DMG installer. This has created 2 folders, `mysql-5.5.15-osx10.6-x86_64` and `mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86_64` with a symlink from `/usr/local/mysql/` leading to the newer one. My databases are still in the old folder, in the `data` folder.

Is it OK to just delete the new data folder, then move the old data folder into the newly installed folder (`/usr/local/mysql-5.5.15-osx10.6-x86_64`) using this:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86_64/data /usr/local/mysql-5.5.15-osx10.6-x86_64/data
```

Are there any gotchas I need to worry about? Is it smarter to just change this in the configuration file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at your my.cnf file to see which folder it is pointing to as the datadir.  If you delete the folder it's pointing to, it won't know where to find your data.  You can change this value to point to where ever you want your data stored.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I added the line `datadir=/usr/local/mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86_64/data` to `my.cnf` and MySQL finds my databases again. Would there be any problem with just copying the `data` directory to the new MySQL folder (and changing `my.cnf`)? I'd like to delete the old MySQL folder completely.

Comment: You should be able to just move the data whereever you want and point my.cnf to the correct location, so long as you do it when the database isn't running, although that might be obvious.